# cakephp 3 tree behavior on associated model

Tags: cakephp, tree, associations, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.4.2 and am doing the [blog tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-three.html) to dive back into the new cakephp. I decided to follow the tutorial but to package it as a plugin.

There is an Articles Model and a Categories Model and we use the Tree Behavior on the CategoriesTable.php initialize() method.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('categories');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Tree');

    $this->belongsTo('ParentCategories', [
        'className' => 'Blog.Categories',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Articles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'className' => 'Blog.Articles'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('ChildCategories', [
        'className' => 'Blog.Categories',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    ]);
}
```

When you call the treeList finder method in the CategoriesController.php add or edit function it works fine and the threaded list shows up nicely in the select list of the form.

The ArticlesController.php add and edit functions

```
public function add()
{
    $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
    }
    $this->set('article', $article);

    $categories = $this->Articles->Categories->find('treeList');
    $this->set(compact('categories'));
}
```

throws an error:

```
Unknown finder method "treeList"
```

I have tried instantiating the Tree behavior in the ArticlesTable.php as I have done in the CategoriesTable.php (though I don't think that should be necessary) but that doesn't work - and the error persists.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

debug from  `debug($this->Articles->Categories->target());`

`/plugins/Blog/src/Controller/Admin/ArticlesController.php (line 51)
object(Cake\ORM\Table) {

```
'registryAlias' => 'Categories',
'table' => 'categories',
'alias' => 'Categories',
'entityClass' => '\Cake\ORM\Entity',
'associations' => [],
'behaviors' => [],
'defaultConnection' => 'default',
'connectionName' => 'default'
```

}`

ArticlesTable.php initialize function:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('articles');
    $this->displayField('title');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Your post is missing the actual code that triggers the error... it's hard to give any advice without seeing that.

Comment: That was silly of me - sorry. I have edited the question with the add function. Apologies.

Comment: Looks like `$this->Articles->Categories` is not what you expect it to be. If you debug `$this->Articles->Categories->target()` you'll probably see that it's an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` instead of your concrete `ArticlesTable` class? What does the `initialize()` method of your `ArticlesTable` class look like?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have added the debug code above and the ArticlesTable.php initialize method

Comment: That `belongsTo` association should point to `Blog.Categories`.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I feel very silly. Thanks for your time assisting me. How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145858/discussion-between-manu-and-ndm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ndm for pointing this out...

The belongsTo association should point to Blog.Categories